# VUE Error when run test unit

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, webpack, vue.js, karma-webpack

I just added test unit, and when I run it using `npm run unit`, I got the error and test will failed.
But, when I run `npm run dev` everything looks fine, I don't know what the hack is happened. I think when I run with `npm run unit`, `sass-loader` cannot recognize the partial files and will throw new error `variable undefined`.

Here's my code
https://github.com/rohmanhm/unobuilder/tree/test

Here is the error message.

> ✘ rohmanhm  ~/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder   test  sudo yarn unit
>   yarn unit v0.20.3 $ cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start
>   test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run Hash: 6fdcbeffca85c85952cb
>   Version: webpack 2.2.1 Time: 59663ms
>                                                Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>                   static/fonts/lato100.ded7187.woff2  23.5 kB          [emitted]
>                         static/img/icons.76d3910.svg  49.4 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato300.100dadd.eot  32.7 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato700.43a8fa5.eot  35.2 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato900.4f7ab78.eot  33.8 kB          [emitted]
>               static/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.7ae9b8b.eot   110 kB          [emitted]
>         static/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ea07932.eot   128 kB          [emitted]
>          static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.561e4b6.eot   107 kB          [emitted]  static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.5f467e7.eot   124 kB 
>   [emitted]
>             static/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.e487b7c.eot   131 kB          [emitted]
>              static/fonts/OpenSans-Light.8040375.eot   108 kB          [emitted]
>        static/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.6725fc4.eot   133 kB          [emitted]
>            static/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.a35546e.eot   106 kB          [emitted]
>           static/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.0ea0450.eot   108 kB          [emitted]   static/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.da06141.eot   131 kB 
>   [emitted]
>                       static/img/lato100.1e9336b.svg   233 kB          [emitted]
>                       static/img/lato300.1aed0c8.svg   236 kB          [emitted]
>                       static/img/lato700.cfdfec6.svg   250 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>                       static/img/lato900.030643b.svg   238 kB          [emitted]
>                 static/img/OpenSans-Bold.d6291f8.svg   270 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>           static/img/OpenSans-BoldItalic.a54aba8.svg   291 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>            static/img/OpenSans-ExtraBold.c1deb2d.svg   272 kB          [emitted]  [big]    static/img/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.9704305.svg
>   290 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>               static/img/OpenSans-Italic.d6671d4.svg   298 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>                static/img/OpenSans-Light.d79f021.svg   264 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>          static/img/OpenSans-LightItalic.b64e991.svg   298 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>              static/img/OpenSans-Regular.f641a7d.svg   272 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>             static/img/OpenSans-Semibold.66da250.svg   270 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>       static/img/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ddc348f.svg   296 kB          [emitted]  [big]
>                     static/fonts/lato100.4abb6ba.ttf  76.1 kB          [emitted]
>                    static/fonts/lato100.126c1aa.woff  33.3 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato100.f8e1b1b.eot  30.2 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato300.ad9795e.ttf  83.3 kB          [emitted]
>                    static/fonts/lato300.6f934cd.woff  36.3 kB          [emitted]
>                   static/fonts/lato300.3e86c49.woff2  25.4 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato700.a30435e.ttf  82.4 kB          [emitted]
>                    static/fonts/lato700.fd37395.woff  35.9 kB          [emitted]
>                   static/fonts/lato700.649e18e.woff2  25.6 kB          [emitted]
>                     static/fonts/lato900.01f5fcc.ttf    77 kB          [emitted]
>                    static/fonts/lato900.c208c97.woff  34.4 kB          [emitted]
>                   static/fonts/lato900.f377f44.woff2  25.4 kB          [emitted]
>               static/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.5a10091.ttf   110 kB          [emitted]
>              static/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.8926673.woff  63.6 kB          [emitted]
>         static/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.c36b5ac.ttf   128 kB          [emitted]
>        static/fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.7be88e7.woff  73.6 kB          [emitted]
>          static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.5d29c43.ttf   107 kB          [emitted]
>         static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.3ae3245.woff  62.5 kB          [emitted]  static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.4595d7f.ttf   124 kB 
>   [emitted] static/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.4f44077.woff  71.7 kB 
>   [emitted]
>             static/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.9b30f13.ttf   131 kB          [emitted]
>            static/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.5250746.woff  76.1 kB          [emitted]
>              static/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ecb4572.ttf   107 kB          [emitted]
>             static/fonts/OpenSans-Light.963eb32.woff  62.8 kB          [emitted]
>        static/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.26f1e68.ttf   133 kB          [emitted]
>       static/fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.97534dd.woff  76.4 kB          [emitted]
>            static/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.cd72963.ttf   106 kB          [emitted]
>           static/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ac327c4.woff  63.7 kB          [emitted]
>           static/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.b5a0ae8.ttf   108 kB          [emitted]
>          static/fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.56bfcae.woff  64.4 kB          [emitted]   static/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.1c0b4eb.ttf   131 kB 
>   [emitted]  static/fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ec55f26.woff  75.6 kB 
>   [emitted]
>                                             index.js  12.5 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  index.js chunk    {0} index.js (index.js) 5.22 MB
>   [entry] [rendered]
>       [5] ./src/utils.js 61.3 kB {0} [built]    [11] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]    [12]
>   ./src/store/mutation-types.js 11.8 kB {0} [built]    [14]
>   ./src/client.js 96.6 kB {0} [built]    [57] ./~/vue/dist/vue.common.js
>   242 kB {0} [built]   [153] ./~/function-bind/index.js 111 bytes {0}
>   [built]   [186] ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$) 11.1 kB {0} [built]
>   [187] ./test/unit/specs .spec$ 177 bytes {0} [built]   [463]
>   ./src/assets/scss/layout/_properties.scss 1.21 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]   [464] ./src/assets/scss/layout/_right_panel.scss 1.21 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]   [465] ./src/assets/scss/layout/_screen_tools.scss
>   1.21 kB {0} [optional] [built]   [466] ./src/assets/scss/layout/_top_panel.scss 1.2 kB {0} [optional] [built]
>   [467] ./src/assets/scss/layout/_workspace.scss 1.2 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]   [468] ./src/assets/scss/main.scss 1.16 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]   [475] ./test/unit/index.js 505 bytes {0} [built]
>        + 461 hidden modules
>
> WARNING in ./src/components/panel/RightPanelProperties.vue There are
>   multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead
>   to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
>   case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelProperties.vue
>       Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src /^./(?!main(.js)?$)/
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelProperties.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanel.vue
>
> WARNING in ./src/components/panel/RightPanelSwitcher.vue There are
>   multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead
>   to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
>   case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelSwitcher.vue
>       Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src /^./(?!main(.js)?$)/
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelSwitcher.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanel.vue
>
> WARNING in
>   ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/panel/RightPanelProperties.vue
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This
>   can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with
>   other case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module
>   identifiers:
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelProperties.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelProperties.vue
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelProperties.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelProperties.vue
>
> WARNING in
>   ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/panel/RightPanelSwitcher.vue
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This
>   can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with
>   other case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module
>   identifiers:
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelSwitcher.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/RightPanelSwitcher.vue
>   * /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelSwitcher.vue
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/components/panel/rightPanelSwitcher.vue
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/base.scss
>   Module build failed:
>         @include OpenSans;
>                 ^
>         No mixin named OpenSans
>
> Backtrace:    src/assets/scss/base/_fields.scss:22
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/base/_fields.scss
>   (line 22, column 16)  @ ./src/assets/scss/base.scss 4:14-148  @ ./src
>   ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout.scss
>   Module build failed:   background-color: lighten($warm-grey, 20);
>                              ^
>         Undefined variable: "$warm-grey".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_base.scss
>   (line 7, column 29)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout.scss 4:14-150  @ ./src
>   ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/base/_fields.scss
>   Module build failed: [class*='#{$prefix}-fields-'] {
>             ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/base/_fields.scss
>   (line 1, column 12)  @ ./src/assets/scss/base/_fields.scss 4:14-157  @
>   ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/canvas/_elements.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix}:not(.preview--mode) {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/canvas/_elements.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/canvas/_elements.scss 4:14-159
>   @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/base/_fonts.scss
>   Module build failed:   src:
>   url('#{$assets_path}/fonts/lato/lato100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
>                                                     ^
>         Undefined variable: "$assets-path".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/base/_fonts.scss
>   (line 6, column 52)  @ ./src/assets/scss/base/_fonts.scss 4:14-156  @
>   ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_accordion.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_accordion.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_accordion.scss
>   4:14-160  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_canvas_tools.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_canvas_tools.scss
>   (line 3, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_canvas_tools.scss
>   4:14-163  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_base.scss
>   Module build failed:   background-color: lighten($warm-grey, 20);
>                              ^
>         Undefined variable: "$warm-grey".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_base.scss
>   (line 7, column 29)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_base.scss 4:14-155  @
>   ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_left_panel.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_left_panel.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_left_panel.scss
>   4:14-161  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_properties.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_properties.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_properties.scss
>   4:14-161  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_right_panel.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_right_panel.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_right_panel.scss
>   4:14-162  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_screen_tools.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_screen_tools.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_screen_tools.scss
>   4:14-163  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_top_panel.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_top_panel.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_top_panel.scss
>   4:14-160  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/scss/layout/_workspace.scss
>   Module build failed: .#{$prefix} {   ^
>         Undefined variable: "$prefix".
>         in /Users/rohmanhm/Desktop/Code/Works/unobuilder/src/assets/scss/layout/_workspace.scss
>   (line 1, column 4)  @ ./src/assets/scss/layout/_workspace.scss
>   4:14-160  @ ./src ^./(?!main(.js)?$)  @ ./test/unit/index.js 02 03
>   2017 16:16:01.321:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at
>   http://0.0.0.0:9876/ 02 03 2017 16:16:01.328:INFO [launcher]:
>   Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency 02 03 2017
>   16:16:01.510:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS 02 03 2017
>   16:16:09.946:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on
>   socket iTpEd0seJoQ2f3fcAAAA with id 5748459 02 03 2017
>   16:16:19.949:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1
>   times), because no message in 10000 ms. PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X
>   0.0.0) ERROR   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
>
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (10.013
>   secs / 0 secs)
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

Please help me to resolve this problems.
Thanks.

Comment: Read the error message – you have multiple undefined variables and mixins.

Comment: yes I know, but when I run with `npm run dev` it's run smoothly. With the same config

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by replace from `true` to `false`

from `const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)`

to `const srcContext = require.context('../../src', false, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)`

Comment: Sorry for dead link. 
updated link https://github.com/rohmanhm/unobuilder/blob/develop/test/unit/index.js#L15